# How do I reset my game and play again (kivy, python) without closing the game?

Tags: python, kivy

I am a beginner coder in Kivy/Python. I made this simple math game where the player clicks the "*addition button*" in the Homepage and goes to the game. The game starts with a *3,2,1 GO!* countdown followed by a *60sec timer* to answer as many questions. The questions are randomly generated. After the 60s, a popup box appears to show the player stats (eg. Score, No. of questions answered etc).

However, when I return to the homepage ie.MainPage() and open up the AdditionPage(), The addition page does not start from the beginning.
Could someone help me understand what I could do to solve this issue?

HomePage = *MainPage() Class*

Addition Game = *AdditionPage() Class*

Here is my main.py code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from random import randint
from kivy.animation import Animation


class MainPage(Screen):
    pass

class AdditionPage(Screen):
    total_question = 0
    right_answers = 0
    top = []
    bot = []
    user_ans = []
    real_ans = []
    ctdown = 65
    ctdown2 = 65
    streak = 0
    thescore = 0
    count = 4
    ## All OBJECTPROPERTIES are deleted here to make the code concise
  

    def countdown(self, *args):     # countdown before the game starts (eg. 3,2,1 GO!)
       self.count = self.count - 1
       if self.count > 0:
            self.time.opacity = 1
            self.time.text = str(self.count)
            self.animate(1)
       elif self.count == 0:
           self.time.opacity = 1
           self.time.text = "GO!"
           self.time.font_size = 10
           self.expand(0.8)
       else:
           self.time.text = ''

    # method for the game
    def addition(self):
        self.answer.focus = True
        self.correct.text = ""
        if self.answer.text != "":
            usernumber = self.answer.text.isdigit()   # check if user info is a number
            if usernumber == True:
                sum = int(self.top_num.text) + int(self.bot_num.text)
                str_sum = str(sum)
                if str_sum == self.answer.text:
                    self.right_answers = self.right_answers + 1
                    self.total_question = self.total_question + 1
                    self.scorean()
                    self.streak = self.streak + 1
                    if self.streak >= 3:
                        self.enterin()
                        self.correct.color = (242 / 255, 166 / 255, 10 / 255, 1)
                        st = str(self.streak)
                        self.correct.text = ("Streak: " + st)

                else:
                    self.total_question = self.total_question + 1
                    self.top.append(self.top_num.text)
                    self.bot.append(self.bot_num.text)
                    self.user_ans.append(self.answer.text)
                    self.real_ans.append(str_sum)
                    self.scorered()
                    self.streak = 0
            else:
                self.total_question = self.total_question + 1     # if user input is not a number
                print("Not a number")
                self.correct.opacity = 1
                self.correct.text = "Not a number"
                self.correct.font_size= 25
                self.correct.color = (235/255, 139/255, 0, 0.8)


        self.operator.text = "+"
        i = randint(11, 99)
        self.top_num.text = str(i)

        j = randint(11, 99)
        self.bot_num.text = str(j)


    # method to add the labels on the screen
    def displayer(self):

        topnum = self.top
        botnum = self.bot
        user_ans = self.user_ans
        real_ans = self.real_ans


    def clkwork(self, *args):       # method for the game timer (starts at 60seconds, ends at 0secs)
        self.ctdown = self.ctdown - 1
        if self.ctdown > 0:        
            if self.ctdown <= 5:     # the clock is less than 5 seconds
                self.clock.color= self.clock_name.color = (1,0,0,1)
                self.clock_name.font_size = self.clock.font_size = 28
                self.clock.text = str(self.ctdown)

            else:
                self.clock.text = str(self.ctdown)
        else:
            return False

    # method to add label on popup screen
    def percent(self):
        if self.total_question > 0:       # if the user has answered atleast one question
            percent = int(self.right_answers / self.total_question * 100)
            time = str(int(60 / self.total_question))
            attemps = str(self.total_question)
            str_percent = str(percent)
            self.percentage.text = (str_percent + "%")
            self.attempts.text = attemps
            self.the_seconds.text = (time + " secs")

            if percent == 100:
                self.percentage.color = (0,1,0,1)
            elif percent >= 80 and percent < 100:
                self.percentage.color = (1, 1, 0,1)
            elif percent >= 50 and percent < 80:
                self.percentage.color = (250/255, 194/255,0,1 )
            else:
                self.percentage.color = (255/255, 0/255,0,1 )

        elif self.total_question == 0:       # if the user did not answer any questions
            self.aq.opacity = 0
            self.percentage.opacity = 0
            self.no_ques.opacity = 1
            self.time_label.opacity = 0
            self.the_seconds.opacity = 0
            self.thescore_label.opacity = 0
            self.attempts.opacity = 0
            self.no_ques2.opacity = 1
        else:
            return -1

    # method to add popup screen
    def popupbox(self, *args):
        self.ctdown2 = self.ctdown2 - 1
        if self.ctdown2 == 0:           # the popup box will show up at 0 seconds
            self.ann(self.popup)
            self.score.opacity = 0
            self.next.disabled = True
            self.scorechange()
            self.percent()
            self.go_home.disabled = False
            self.operator.opacity = 0
            self.answer.opacity = 0
            self.next.opacity = 0
            self.go_home.pos_hint = {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y' :0.12}

    # method for the add the score
    def scorechange(self):
        score = int(self.score.text)
        if score < 10:
            self.ids.final_score.text = ('0'+ self.score.text)
        else:
            self.ids.final_score.text = self.score.text

    def on_enter(self):
        self.top_num.opacity = 0
        self.bot_num.opacity = 0
        self.operator.opacity = 0
        self.addition()
        self.timer = Clock.schedule_interval(self.countdown, 1)     # the 3,2,1 GO
        self.timer1 = Clock.schedule_interval(self.clkwork, 1)      # the countdown from 60seconds
        self.timer2 = Clock.schedule_interval(self.popupbox, 1)     # time for the popup box

        # return timer, timer1, timer2


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = WindowManager()
        add = AdditionPage()
        sm.add_widget(MainPage(name="main"))
        sm.add_widget(AdditionPage(name="addition"))
        sm.current = "main"
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: You have to reset the game state of `AdditionPage` screen to the initial values. I couldn't get your code to run - too many things missing kv & ObjectProperties. But add a method that will reset everything needed once the user clicks "Start new game" button. E.g. reset `total_question`, `right_answers` etc.

Comment: Got it boss. It works now. thanks